# button onclick does not fire after typing text in an input-field

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, focus

I made a simple calculator.

User can enter a value in an input-field, then click the '+' button. 
The focus remains on the input-field, so the user directly can enter a new value after clicking on the +. The mouse position remains on the '+' button, so he can click again after entering a new value.
However, clicking this time, no event at all is fired. After approx. 1 second it is possible again, the click is fired. Please explain.

N.b. I experience the same behaviour with online calculators, e.g. http://web2.0calc.com/

The html code:

```
<input type='text' id=calc size=14 style='text-align:right' ></input>
<button type='button' onclick= 'Plus()'>+</button>
```

and script:

```
 // init:
  document.getElementById('calc').value = '' 
  document.getElementById('calc').focus()
  //
  function Plus(){
  // check input, add to total
  document.getElementById('calc').value = '' // clears input after add
  document.getElementById('calc').focus()    // keeps focus on input
   }
```

Comment: Did you try a different browser, a different pc, maybe via mobile device, etc. to make sure it is in the code and not a plugin side effect or something like that?

Comment: I use Firefox, but tested it in IE and Edge as well. I do not have other problems. I do not use plugins.

Answer (score 2):

The example link you gave works perfectly fine in my machine. The delay of 1s that you mention might be a performance issue because of old browser, slow machine etc.

Comment: It's true, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cmog5asd/3/) out. Also, you don't need the input closing tag, since it is a void element

Comment: I use the latest version of Firefox and I experience no other performance issues.